# C++ Qt How do you make a label display a movie (gif) that you created using the form?

Tags: c++, qt, label, gif, movie

I have created a label in the form UI and I would like to make it display a GIF using code in `main`. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure what to put in place of the "???????".  How can I make this label display a GIF?

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMovie>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;

    QMovie *movie = new QMovie(":/Gifs/Welcome_animation2.gif");
    QLabel *lblMovie = new QLabel();
    lblMovie->setMovie(??????????);
    movie->start();

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setMovie) you would `lblMovie->setMovie(movie);`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by CoryKramer, you should just use `lblMovie->setMovie(movie)`. However, the problem seens to be that you're not setting the movie to the correct QLabel (ie. lblMovie is not the same object shown on your window)
You probably have to create the QMovie inside your Dialog class, and there you set the movie to the QLabel by using `ui->lblMovie->setMovie(movie)`. If it really must be created outside, then you should add a public method to allow it.
Take a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html for more information about proper usage of ui files

Comment: Or instead of doing something like `w.ui->lblMovie->setMovie(movie)`, create the `QMovie` object inside the `Dialog` class and set it to the label inside that class. After all the `ui` variable is private by default (as it should be). Another option is to use a function inside the `Dialog` class that takes a `QMovie` pointer as a parameter and sets it to the label.

Comment: yes, that's better. I've changed the answer to better reflect this. Thanks